# How to get users email and fd id using facebook login with graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working for the first time with facebook API. From there documentation I found we can fetch name as below
console.log(response.name);
But How can I can also fetch email and fbid ?

Thanks,
Enamul

```
<?php ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'f', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//localhost/practices/phpTest/fblogin/login.php/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // connected
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
      login();
    } else {
        // not_logged_in
      login();
    }
    });

    // Additional init code here

  };

  function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
          testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
    }

  function testAPI() {

    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
<?php ?>
```

Comment: are yout through or not? comment if not, __Accept__ the answer if yes.

Comment: @ThePCWizard sorry for late accept. I was away for some time so I could not test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you access name. i.e

`response.email` and `response.id`

but to fetch email address you must have the permission to access it.

Add `scope="email"` to your FB Login Button.

[EDIT]

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
        testAPI();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, { scope: 'email' });
    }

function testAPI() {

    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.' + ' Email: ' + response.email + ' Facebook ID: ' + response.id);
    });
}
```

Here's a good tutorial for beginners: http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/404-working-with-facebook-javascript-sdk

Comment: I have  posted my code. Please tell me what change I should made in my code.

Comment: Tried the login example: <fb:login-button 
  scope="public_profile,email"
  onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>, the response contains name and id only, no email. what is wrong?

Answer (score 27):

In addition to adding scope="email" to the button, you need to specify which fields to return.

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile, email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-size="large">
```

```
function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, email'}, function(response) {
        console.log( response );
        console.log( response.email );
    });
}
```

For full code structure take a look at the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).

Comment: This should be the answer! The 2nd argument, `params` for `FB.api()` was key!

Comment: I agree with @KevinWang ; this is the correct answer. While the official documentation talked about the scope, the unmentioned ```FB.api()``` requiring additional param ```fields``` was the key to actually reading the data; this was not written in FB's sample tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else is having trouble with retrieving users' email specifically, please note that Facebook won't allow you to access users' email while your app is still listed as "in-development." After switching to a "in-production" in your Facebook Developer Dashboard, email should become available. Hope this helps someone out there, as I wasted a lot of time tonight struggling to retrieve users' email.

Email: "Not available to all users because your app is not live"

[image]

Comment: This is real? One restriction to use with localhost restricts other needs to test if application works? Is there any logic in there?

Comment: No, this is just wrong. You won’t be able to ask any users that do not have a role in the app, to login to it _at all_ in the first place, while it is still in dev mode. But this has nothing to do with the availability of that permission for those users, that _can_ login while the app is in dev mode.

Answer (score 2):

change code to following

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
});

FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response) {
  console.log('Good to see you, '+response.name + '---'+response.email);
});
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, providing details as to how to reached the conclusion and your thought process will surely help the fellow asker. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Also, format your code properly